# Android app from Beta to Production without "(beta)"

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services

I have uploaded production APK [Code version 3(1.0.1)] with a higher version code than alpha[Code version 1(1.0.0)] or beta[Code version 2(1.0.0)] APK but i see in Google Play Store Mynameapp"(beta)". Please, someone can help me ?[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xmo1g.png) [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlgL7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you did as described here as should:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

I checked in Playstore and it's fine now, Don't worry about it.

[image]

Comment: So I did not make any mistake then I hope. I always "(beta)" here so I still patience.

Comment: I think you're fine ;)

Comment: Lol the real problem is that my account has been added as a beta tester. That's why I had "(beta)". I left the beta tester group and uninstall the application and I no longer have the "beta" display.

Comment: @AkMax so only beta testers see this as Beta in the name?

Comment: @batmaci yes of course, it is only beta testers who can see this as beta in the name